# Get Values from columns corresponding to some values in another column till we get same value in second column

Tags: r, dataframe

I know the title is not clear. But I will explain with example

I have got a data frame 'df' with two columns A and B.

[dataset df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X01G.png)

I want to add new column C if B == "n" then it will have the values from corresponding rows of column A till we get another "n" in column B, after that it will have the value of corresponding row till next "n"

My required dataframe is like this

[required data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG94m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyverse functions, you can do it like this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(A = c(2,1,3,4,5,6,1,7,8,9,4),
             B = c("n", "", "", "n", "", "", "n", "n", "", "", ""))

df %>% 
  mutate(C = ifelse(B == "n", A, NA)) %>% 
  fill(C, .direction = "down")
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked, I used "" instead of NA which didn't make other rows (not matching condition) blank, so fill function didn't work.